# Doubt in homeomorphism of product spaces

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Let $X,Y,Z$ topological spaces. Suppose that product spaces $X \times Y$ and $X \times Z$ are homeomorphic. It's true that $Y$ and $Z$ are homeomorphics? Since that the projection map is only continuous I don't know if this result is really true.

I am interested in the validity of this result to conclude that $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not homeomorphic

Comment: The result is false.

Comment: have a counterexample?

Comment: Yes. Have some work of your own to show us?

Comment: is that actually what I was trying to show was that it wasn't possible to put a metric on $ \mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ so that this manifold had constant sectional curvature. For that, it was enough to show that its universal covering ($\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}$) is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^3$, $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{H}^3$. And then I thought if this result would not be true and if it was I would guarantee that $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N} \times \{1\}$ (all spaces considered with the discrete topology), because they are in bijection with each other and any map is continuous in the discrete topology (so any bijection will be a homeomorphism). Obviously $\{1\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

As for your second question, note that $(x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1}, z) \mapsto (e^{z} x_1, \cdots, e^z x_{n+1})$ is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, so an homeomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ would imply an homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. But  $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ is not contractible (while $\mathbb{R}^n$ obviously is): indeed, it retracts onto $\mathbb{S}^n$, and $\mathbb{S}^n$ is not contractible. Therefore no such homeomorphism can exist, and in particular $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Valeu Matheus!!!!